# Dashboard page title displaying at bottom of the page

Tags: magento2, wishlist, dashboard

In all dashboard page titles displyed the bottom. I need to display at top as regular place. Any one please help me.
In my layout page

```
<body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" as="top">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">My Wish List</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
             <block class="Dcw\Orders\Block\Index" name="bids" template="Dcw_Orders::bids.phtml" after='page.main.title'>
             </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
```

[image]

Comment: please pass the site url to check , it can be a little css issue

Comment: Here i pasted the screen shot. Display order is whistlist form after title.  https://www.screencast.com/t/3OyCXuhGtua8

Comment: how can I debug from screenshot

Comment: is there any css issue?